# Webstorm fully customized themes

Tags: webstorm

Is there any fully customized theme, not just for syntax but "look and feel" kind of a theme? Or we stuck with only a choice between `Default` and `Darcula`?

for (ver 7-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean suctom l&f? It's technically possible to install any third-party L&F into JVM (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) and use it in WebStorm, but it will most likely look ugly and break the UI in many places. If you decide to go this route, start with the Substance.
Note that implementing a custom L&F with custom colors would be a tough task, it took a lot of resources for us to make the Darcula theme.